# How to group data returned from SQL and convert in JSON?

Tags: python

I have the following data coming from SQL result:

```
Grade Marks
A   75
B   78
B   24
C   23
A   29
A   49
```

and I have to make a JSON structure like:

```
"A": {75,29,49},
"B": {78,24},
"C": {23}
```

I know there are multiple ways to do it like involving dicts and list or `itertools` but unable to figure out a cleaner way to do it because data is variable and it'd keep coming from the DB.

Comment: What is the type of your SQL data?

Comment: If you're fetching the results directly from the database using a connector, you can utilize JSON database functions.

In SQL Server, there's `FOR JSON AUTO`, and for MariaDB/MySQL, you can use  `JSON_ARRAYAGG` along with  `JSON_OBJECT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that the data to be in the form of 2-D array. Then you can do in this way:

```
data = [['A',75],['B',78],['B',24],['C',23],['A',29],['A',49]]
out = {}
for i,j in data:
    if i not in out:
        out[i]=set()
    out[i].add(j)
print(out)
```

If you are getting the data in the dictionary type in this form, you can use `itertools.groupby` in this way:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [
    {'mark': '23', 'grade': 'C'},
    {'mark': '75', 'grade': 'A'},
    {'mark': '24', 'grade': 'B'},
    {'mark': '49', 'grade': 'A'},
    {'mark': '29', 'grade': 'A'},
    {'mark': '24', 'grade': 'B'}
]

out = {}

data= sorted(data,key = itemgetter('grade'))
for key, value in groupby(data,key = itemgetter('grade')):
    
    out[key]=set()
    for k in value:
        
        out[key].add(k['mark'])
print(out)
```